# Node-JDBC: Unexpected behavior, program doesn't exit

Tags: node.js, jdbc

I have created a small .js file with this lines of code

```
// test.js
const JDBC = require('jdbc');

console.log('should end')
```

If I execute this code, the execution of this program will last forever
[image]

However, if I comment/remove the line where I require jdbc library, the program ends correctly.

[image]

Platform: Windows 11

node version: v14.19.1

Comment: What do you mean by "last forever"? As in your terminal remains open when it executes? Or you can see the program in task manager still running after it should end?

Comment: please explain us how the script is called

Comment: @meropis if i run the test.js the execution of the file should end after the execution of the console.log, but it won't

Comment: @tom the script is called with ```node test```